# How to get Firebase realtime database keys, with out loading whole child object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[FIREBASE REAL-TIME DATABASE structure Image attachment](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_m4LYxWg2zGHn9CfO4BdfIZ9wqZMpoxD/view?usp=sharing)

As you can see in structure, the online key node has sub-nodes with number and value as a Long string.

There are many sub-nodes(27,000).

when I use

`firebase.database().ref().child('12321/Audio/060820/Online').once('value',sn=>{ //value event listener once //I need only top one key-value pair, i,e 132607-Data:....... })`

this method loads all Online node which takes more than a minute But I need Efficient mode to get only a few latest entries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `limitToLast` or limitToFirst`:

```
firebase.database().ref().child('12321/Audio/060820/Online').limitToFirst(10).once('value',sn=>{ //value event listener once //I need only top one key-value pair, i,e 132607-Data:....... })
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#limittofirst

Comment: It is was helpful. is there a way to get next 10 and so on. without deleting the first 10

Comment: You can store the first 10 in a list and then do another query

Comment: I can only read, the audio branch, I can read first 10 by using limittofirst(10) method. How can I get 10 to 20 records and so on,